# Difficulties in comparing two ints. How to remember the result?

Tags: android, int, comparison, counter

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {
int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;
int count3;
private static final int MILLIS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
  private static final int SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN = 11;

  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  private CountDownTimer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);

    final TextView t11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t11);
    final TextView t12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t12);   

    t11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             t11.setText("10 seconds");
             count = 0; 
             mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 3000);

        }
    });

    Button butb1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.butb1);
    butb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            t12.setText("" + ++count);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy(); }

private void showTimer(int countdownMillis) {

      timer = new CountDownTimer(countdownMillis, MILLIS_PER_SECOND) {
      @Override
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          final TextView t11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t11);
        t11.setText(" " +
        millisUntilFinished / MILLIS_PER_SECOND + "SECONDS");
      }
      @Override
        public void onFinish() {

          Button butb1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.butb1);
          butb1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
          timer.cancel();
          final TextView t11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t11);
          if (count>count1)
            {
                t11.setTextSize(60);
                t11.setText("GREAT!");

            }
          else {

              t11.setText("BAD!");}

        }
      }.start();
    }

 private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Button butb1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.butb1);
        butb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
              showTimer(SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
    }
  };


}
```

This is the code I have. What I need to do is to remember the value of 'count' and transfer it to 'count1' in order to compare count and count1 when timer starts for the second time, so if count>count1 then post "Great" and if not - "Bad" . I cannot figure out how to make it, I guess the third int is needed in this case, that is why I added count3, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution

```
 if (count>count1)
      {
        count1 = count;         
    t21.setText("GREAT!");  }
```